# Facebook Custom Page and App directions?

Tags: php, facebook

I have to develop Facebook app and put it into custom made facebook page as a side widget.
what are alternatives on customizing Fan page (one I googled is through static FBML - FBML)?
also I need to provide backend part in clients site so banner in the page can be changed from there. considering this I assume the "static FBML" is not an option right ?
anyhow any directions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

FBML stands for Facebook Markup Language. [Here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBML) is the Facebook Developer page about it, and [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Allowed_FBML_and_HTML_Tags) is a list of allowed FBML and HTML tags within Facebook apps.

I'm not sure what is meant by "static" FBML, since the FBML can be generated dynamically by your PHP code just like you could do when outputting HTML. But hopefully one of these links will be of some help to you.

Comment: Static FBML is a App that makes it easy to customize the fan Page

Comment: what is the other way to cutomize fan page?

Comment: Static FBML looks like it's just an app for Facebook users to use to customise their own pages. So it doesn't sound like what you're looking for.

What you need to look at are the Facebook Developer docs, specifically regarding Application Tabs.

See:
http://developers.facebook.com/get_started.php
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Tabbed_Profile

Facebook has a sample application you can download from their site, that lets you play around with the various features their API offers. You can check it out at

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/New_Design_Sample_App